# How to connect string with a object method?

Tags: java

I have the following problems: I've got 20 files, that I need to fill based on user input. I have the list of strings, which is the list fields name used in all of the 20 files. Now, what I would like to do, is to run each of those strings against each form, so that if field exist, I can fill it in, based on expression I provide.

So for example, I would have something like that (pseudo code):

```
for all files
    for all strings in sting list
        if field with name string exists, use SOME METHOD on given object
```

Now, as of know, I store the list of the strings in the database.

My question is: how can I assign a method (like `User.getFirstName()`), to each of the string in array, so that described pesudo code would run?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like the Command Pattern.

Comment: @rmlan, can you explain?

Comment: Sure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way to assign Value to Key is `Map`.

```
Map<String, Function<T,R>> mapping;
```

Comment: this is what I've ended up doing. I will leave the question open for a while, and if no-one will add anything, I will accept this as answer